# How do I create a cross server verification during wordpress registration?

Tags: wordpress, web-services, api

I want to limit my Wordpress registration to users found on a certain database. Can I create a verification field during registration that will make an api call to verify this? Can someone point me in a starting direction? I know how to make the call using postman, but beyond that, I am at a lost with where to start.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.